# Where can I see the code generated by Android Data Binding Library?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I'm trying to grasp the [android data binding](http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) technology.

So, following the guide, I've created layout `user_item.xml` and now I can refer to generated `UserItemBinding` class in my code. I can list all possible methods of `UserItemBinding` class (using `ctrl + space` in Android Studio), but I can't see its source code (using `ctrl + click`).

Is there a way to see the sources?

Comment: They are probably in `build/generated/` or `build/intermediates/` somewhere, in your module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated files can be found in the directory `/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/example/databinding/` and `BR.java` is located at `/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug/com/example/BR.java`.